# AWS Boto3: The security token included in the request is invalid for AWS FORECAST

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-forecast

I am trying to query forecast arn in aws but getting the following error :

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('forecastquery')
response = client.query_forecast(
    ForecastArn=' ',
    StartDate='2018-12-31T00:00:00',
    EndDate='2019-12-31T23:00:00',
    Filters={
        'item_id':' '
    }
    )
print(response)
```

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the QueryForecast
>   operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Comment: Is your key valid? Check the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: Try calling another service (eg S3 `list_buckets()`) to check whether this problem has anything to do with Forecast or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the region which you are using. There are few region which required to be enabled. Below regions need to be enable first before using them.
Africa (Cape Town) - af-south-1,
Asia Pacific (Hong Kong) - ap-east-1,
Europe (Milan) - eu-south-1,
Middle East (Bahrain) - me-south-1.

While forecasting these regions might also coming into consideration but as these regions are disabled by default therefore you are getting an error. check out document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-available-regions